# How to turn all index rows into columns and all column headers into index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pretty big dataframe in pandas and want to transform all index rows into column headers und all column headers into index rows. Is there an easy way to do this? I am only aware of `df.pivot_table()`, where I would have to specify my columns and rows (to my knowledge). Since the dataframe is pretty big I am looking for a way to circumvent that. Does someone know a good way?

Comment: Are you wanting to transpose or rename?

Comment: transpose. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just transpose it using [`.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = df.T
```

Example:

```
In [211]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abcde'), data = np.random.randn(6,5))
df

Out[211]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0  1.277750 -0.818470  0.221428 -0.828488  0.086669
1 -1.638219  0.365425 -0.052923 -0.498466  0.731609
2  0.631106 -0.028060  0.445067  0.263992 -2.446687
3 -0.169760 -1.405007  0.334086  0.213003 -0.313874
4  0.221344  1.758491 -0.636134 -1.710499 -1.219083
5  2.022891 -0.512623  0.803830  0.340616  0.884738

In [212]:
df.T

Out[212]:
          0         1         2         3         4         5
a  1.277750 -1.638219  0.631106 -0.169760  0.221344  2.022891
b -0.818470  0.365425 -0.028060 -1.405007  1.758491 -0.512623
c  0.221428 -0.052923  0.445067  0.334086 -0.636134  0.803830
d -0.828488 -0.498466  0.263992  0.213003 -1.710499  0.340616
e  0.086669  0.731609 -2.446687 -0.313874 -1.219083  0.884738
```

or [`.transpose`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas.DataFrame.transpose) if you prefer to be more explicit and like typing